# Browser Compatibility with Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have no problem creating the forms. Some users still have Internet Explorer 8.0 as their browser default. When I send the form link, they cannot open the form? I use Chrome 40 to design the form and have no issues.

What would be the minimum IE version, or any other browser for that matter,  for users to view and complete the form? I'm sure they are able to easily update their browser version.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports IE 8.0 and above for form submissions (links or embedded) and IE 9.0 or above for managing forms, entries and payments.  However, it is important that the browser not be running in quirks mode (as can happen when embedding in older websites).

We perform testing in IE, Chrome, Firefox & Safari, as well as mobile platforms since our forms and administration site work great on phones and tablets too.

If you are encountering a problem with a specific form that is not working in IE 8.0, please submit a bug report and we will take a look!