# Internet Explorer Error

Tags: cognito-forms

Whenever the Cognito form is embedded into my own website, it works great everywhere except IE. Even when we delete all code from the page and simply use the code supplied to embed it it won't work. After refreshing the page a couple times it comes up but generally it won't.

Instead of my form I see:

> Oh No! You are using an unsupported browser. Click Here to upgrade

The click here links takes the user to the Browse Happy website.

Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Please include a link to the page you are trying to embed the form on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of: [Browser Compatibility with Cognito Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74836/browser-compatibility-with-cognito-forms)

If you are seeing this error in a Modern browser (or even in IE 8.0) then the issue is the document type (part of the HTML tag) for the website your are embedding the form into is forcing Internet Explorer to run in quirks-mode and pretend it is an older browser, like IE 7.0 or even IE 5.0.  Cognito Forms relies on browser features that were not available before the release of IE 8.0, like secure cross-domain calls, and will not work in older browsers or older sites with legacy document types.